# Creating an array from dynamically updating arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, axios

I have a trivia app application in my React project, where I fetch some data from an API:

question
wrong answers
correct answer

Now I want to make an array of of both the wrong in right answers and map them so the users get all the possible answers in a random order.

I'm having issues creating the array of `allAnswers`

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=50').then( response =>{
    for(var key in response.data.results){
        const question = [...this.state.question,  response.data.results[key].question]; // here i put the data into state in each category 
        const answer = [...this.state.answer, response.data.results[key].correct_answer];
        const wrongAnswers = [...this.state.wrongAnswers, response.data.results[key].incorrect_answers];
        const allAnswers = [wrongAnswers, answer] // here im trying to collec all possible answers and then later make a handler to check if the given answer was right or wrong 
        this.setState( prevState => ({
            question: question,
            answer: answer,
            wrongAnswers: wrongAnswers,
            allAnswers: allAnswers,
    }));    
}
    });
}
```

So I save 50 questions and respective answers and wrong answers to not send net work requests all the time.

Then I have made a random counter, that I use to map a random question:

```
     <p>{this.state.question[this.state.random]}</p>
```

I then map through the array of all the answers to get each answer displayed:

```
     {this.state.random !== undefined && this.state.wrongAnswers[this.state.random] !== undefined && this.state.allAnswers[this.state.random].map((answer, index) => {  
          console.log(this.state.allAnswers[this.state.random])
            return(
                <form >
                <input type="radio" name="name" value="!!" /> {answer}<br/>
                </form>
               )
            
            })
        })
```

My issue here is that the array of `allAnswers` is just the wrong answers, and I can't find a way to collect all the right and wrong answers in a respective way inside the state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator to concat the two arrays.

```
const answer = [...this.state.answer, response.data.results[key].correct_answer];
        const wrongAnswers = [...this.state.wrongAnswers, response.data.results[key].incorrect_answers];
        const allAnswers = [...answer, ...wrongAnswers];
```

This will result in an array that contains the elements of both answer and wrongAnswers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried and it gives an error saying this.state.allAnswers[this.state.random].map is not a function, when i try to map through it

Comment: the issue is that answer  is a string, and this will result, in concating to the string